# How do I cut out for Kerf-type molding on older door frame

Tags: woodworking

I have a house built in 1910.  I'm trying to improve the weatherstripping on a few outside doors.  I'd like to use [kerf-type weatherstripping](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GT6P6B9).

I saw a This Old House episode where a great [tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEJvpoVrwLk) was used, but sadly that tool can't be found anywhere.

I bought a special [router bit](https://procabinetsupply.com/products/weather-seal-router-bit-double-sided-hexagonal-cmt?variant=39378013651011&gclid=Cj0KCQjwzLCVBhD3ARIsAPKYTcTEb_R45Uww43S-PJpmkpCvfg8eP6mavXqNgoQGUe1W5D-27cr6JsMaAlB4EALw_wcB) for Kerf-type weatherstripping.

It seems like the bit would best be used with a palm router.  I'm a little concerned about using it free-hand, but I can't find anything like that great tool from This Old House.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to my approach, or a suggestion for a good palm router?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with the front door of my house.  I was thinking that you could use a multi-tool with 2 different blades.  First just a straight saw blade to start a kerf.  Then, a grout tool that creates the needed width to install the kerf mounted weatherstripping.

It’ not a quick as what Tom Silva did in that episode, but the multi-tool is already owned.

Answer (score 1):

It is called **Corner Grooving Router Tool**

Here is one from Dewalt as example (not sure where to get it)

[image: dewalt]

Obviously the 45 Dgr will allow you to get in the corner.

Comment: Thanks very much for responding.  This is exactly the tool I'd like, but they don't make it any more.  I can't be found anywhere, including eBay.  Are you aware of a site that sells tools like this?  Or even if there's a 45 degree jig I can attach to a different trim router.  I'd appreciate any ideas you have on where to locate one.  Thanks.

Comment: @user3138025 See my comment on another answer with a link. Also see https://www.conservfirst.com/building_products/ for another option that currently sells these. They are still sold, you just have to look a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your interest in having really good weatherstripping, but there’s a few things at play here.

Cost to benefit-wise, installing kerfed weatherstripping (whether you diy with an expensive tool or — lucky you! — find a pro that can do it these days) is pricey when compared to getting a normal high quality external seal. (You won’t pay more than $100 for an excellent bulb or qlon set… plenty of finishes are available… it’s easy diy.)

In the bigger picture, weatherstripping on a door is one very tiny part of the air leakage in a vintage house. While a let-in weatherstripping system might be fractionally better than alternatives, it’s not going to impact the overall dynamic of the house.

Answer (score 1):

A company called [Conservation Technology](http://www.conservationtechnology.com/building_weatherseals.html) used to sell the grooving tool that you need.  I knew a carpenter who had the tool and the seals and I did my whole house.

Their Web site is a bit of a mystery because they don't show individual items or prices, but I ordered some items from them about 5 years ago.  You might give them a call if interested.

Comment: It is still offered for sale--you can find their product page at http://www.conservationtechnology.com/building_weatherseals_components.html (second item from the bottom) -- it's not that mysterious, you just have to call and order over the phone. Like how all online commerce was done once upon a time.

Answer (score 1):

Try a biscuit tool, which has depth settings and allows you to get a straight line.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best option today is to use a oscillating saw.  Mark its small tooth squared-off blade with a marker 1/2 inch back from the teeth.  Then repeatedly plunge the blade flush with the molding down to that mark to create a flush kerf 1/2 inch deep.  (If you need to move the kerf back from the molding a little, make up a spacer strip to set back the blade.) Because most oscillating blades are only about 1/16 inch thick you'll need to make a second pass to thicken the kerf to fully 1/8 inch.  One way is to stack up several strips of duck tape to be 1/16 inch thick.  Stick that on the jamb to rest the blade on to make the kerf cut thicker.  Then move the tape to continue cutting.

Comment: "*As of 2018, corner groove routers are no longer available anywhere.*" I'd say 'citation needed', but I know this is incorrect--it is still sold by at least two companies, Conservation Technology and ConservFirst.